# Pass comand line parameters to shell script via omprog (rsyslog module)

Tags: linux, shell, logging, rsyslog

Having bad times with passing system log message to shell script as command line parameter via rsyslog module omprog.

My /etc/rsyslog.conf:

```
module(load="omprog")
if $syslogtag contains 'user'
then action(type="omprog" binary="/usr/bin/test")
```

My /usr/bin/test:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf "\n$(date): $1" >> /home/user/sink
```

On running

```
logger qqq
```

I get 'qqq' in /var/log/messages and current timestamp in /home/user/sink.
Upon running

```
/usr/bin/test some_message
```

I get in /home/user/sink current timestamp along with 'some_message'. But as soon as I modify action string in /etc/rsyslog.conf to
either

```
then action(type="omprog" binary="/usr/bin/test some_message")
```

or

```
then action(type="omprog" binary="/usr/bin/test \"$msg\"")
```

I get logger parameter in system log, but nothing in /home/user/sink.
Stuck on that issue for whole day already, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

further info on action parameters not being able to be generated dynamically -- https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/1149

--

```
rgerhards commented on Sep 21, 2016

The key problem is: what shall the action do if a parameter changes? e.g. shut
down existing connection and create a new one? If so, shall it really do this 
if parameters frequently change?

IMHO to handle this decently, the plugin itself must handle these kinds of 
dynamic properties and act accordingly. So there is no generic solution possible.
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand [rsyslog's documentation](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omprog.html), binary is just a literal value, so it's not going to be evaluated against rsyslog variables. Binary - you program/commandline - will be fed via `stdin`, of course you can change template for that action to include only `$msg`, using action's `template` param.

Comment: Seems like I was misled by example in that doc that you refer to. Anyways, as I adjusted my shell script to read from stdin nothing has changed even when I created my template.